# A closed linear functional must be bounded？

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

it‘s a problem from salamon’s functional analysis

> Let $X$ be a real Banach space, Let $Y\subset X$ be a linear subspace, and let $T:Y\to \mathbb{R} $ be a linear functional. show that $T$ is closeable if and only if $T$ is bounded.

The definition of closeable:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, let $dom(A)\subset X$ be a linear subspace, and let $A:dom(A)\to Y$ be a linear operator.  The operator $A$ is called closeable if there exists a closed linear operator $A’: dom(A’)\to Y$ on a linear subspace $dom(A’)\subset X$ such that
> $$dom(A)\subset dom(A’), A’x=Ax, for~all~x\in dom(A)$$

If $T$ is bounded, we can easily show that $T$ is closeable by Hahn-Banach theorem and closed graph theorem.

However, conversely, I don’t know how to deal with it. If $T’$ is a closed linear functional which extends $T$, we cannot get the boundedness of $T’$ since the domain of $T’$ may not be closed, and hence we cannot use closed graph theorem. It seems that we should prove that a closed linear functional must be bounded, but I don’t know how to do it.

I do hope someone can help me.Thanks!

***Update***:

I have some ideas although I’m not sure whether it is right.

Claim: Suppose that $X$ is a normed vector space but not complete, and $T:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a closed linear functional.We can show that $T$ must be bounded.

Proof: If $T$ is unbounded, then $Ker T$ is a dense subspace of $X$. Chose $y\in X\backslash Ker(T)$, and $\left\{ x_n \right\} \subset Ker\left( T \right) $ such that $x_n\to y$.
Note that $Tx_n\to 0$,$x_n\to y$ implies that $Ty=0 $ since $T$ is closed, so it contradicts with the assumtion that $y\notin Ker(T)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to argue by contradiction, your argument is a direct one.

Indeed, let $\{x_n\}\subset\ker T$ be Cauchy. Since $X$ is Banach, there exists $y\in X$ with $y=\lim x_n$. The sequence $\{(x_n,0)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the graph of $T$. As this is closed and $X\times\mathbb R$ is Banach, it is complete; so $(y,0)$ is in the graph of $T$, i.e. $Ty=0$. This shows that $\ker T$ is closed, and so $T$ is bounded (this last implication is where one uses that $T$ is a functional).

Comment: Please upvote if you found this useful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this idea helps you. I'm currently studying something similar for an exam.

We know that the closed graph theorem is iff, and we know that the graph of T' is closed, thus T' is a continuous. This implies that ||T(x)|| <= ||T|| * ||x|| and because T' is a prolongement of T, T is also continuous, i.e. bounded.

I have a question for your second proof: Why is KerT dense?

Comment: You should notice what I have said. The domain of $T‘$ may not be closed，so you cannot use the closed graph thm directly. Besides，unboundedness imply the kernel is dense in infinite dimensional normed space.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Thanks for the clarification !